# MongoDB gets faster when processing repeated queries

Tags: mongodb, performance, web

I am developing a web application with MongoDB. I have noticed a phenomenon that when executing the same query repeatedly, the processing speed boosts and finally converges at a certain point. Like when querying all documents in the collection, the time usage per query will be **100000 ms -> 20000 ms -> 9000ms -> ... -> 500 ms**.

I am wondering what is the reason behind the speed boost? And how to estimate the convergence point?

Comment: Likely just that all the docs are in memory at that point so it doesn't need to hit the disk anymore.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny. I have thought of such cache like mechanism, but wouldn't that be improving the performance to the best once the docs are in the cache? However, based on my observation it improves gradually, so at least not all docs are stored in the cache after each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons, i can give some points.

**First of all, MongoDB is able to choose the best index for your query. To do so, MongoDB use a Query Plans. But this operation take time:**

> If there are no matching entries, the query planner generates
>   candidate plans for evaluation over a trial period. The query planner
>   chooses a winning plan, creates a cache entry containing the winning
>   plan, and uses it to generate the result documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/

**INDEX should be loaded into memory** in order to speed up the performance, this also take time. Try to look at Touch:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/touch/

> The touch command loads data from the data storage layer into memory.
>   touch can load the data (i.e. documents) indexes or both documents and
>   indexes.

**Another reason, the INDEX do not fit into memory** in order to know if this is your case maybe you can check with totalIndexSize

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.totalIndexSize/#db.collection.totalIndexSize

I'm more focused to improve the query-planner side since MongoDB doesn't take the best decision for you all the time.

All this topic should be carefully evaluated in my opinion to avoid performance degrade.

Good Luck!